# Java: How to get the index of file in JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

I have a `JTree` and I have it displaying everything I need, but i want to add what ever file i choose from the `JTree` to a `JTextArea`. I have this been done using a `JList` which all i do is get the selected index of the file in the `JList` and then append that to the `JTextArea`... But looking through the `JTree` there is no method to get the index of the chosen like in the `JList`, I have searched online and have had no luck with finding a solution!

The only way I can think of doing this a having a few methods to search through the `JTree` and at each level return where index of the file is, but that is alot of work so is there any better way to do this? Really what I am asking is what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are only allowing single selection, you can use:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
```

To get selected node. You could create a Map where the key is going to be the DefaultMutableTreeNode, and the associated value could be the String of the file you want to create.

Comment: DefaultMutableTreeNode has a user object property which you can put the file name in, so no need for a separate Map.

Comment: You're right @WalterLaan there is no need for a Map, but in that way he could have any kind of Object instead of a String, so I think it is good practice when you are learning.